# Como pasar consulta SQL a LINQ C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Intento realizar este select pero con LINQ en C# y no lo logro porque me da diferentes resultados, no soy muy experto en LINQ:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.cod_clt,
                C.nom_clt,
                C.dir_clt,
                C.cod_zon,
                V.inicio AS FECHA_VISITA,
                O.dia,
                O.orden,
                C.fec_pln
FROM   erpadmin.cliente C
       INNER JOIN erpadmin.alfac_ruta_orden O
               ON ( C.cod_zon = 'R03'
                    AND O.cod_zon = C.cod_zon
                    AND O.cod_clt = C.cod_clt )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN erpadmin.visita V
                    ON ( C.cod_clt = V.cliente
                         AND V.inicio >= '12/20/2021')
WHERE  O.dia = 'L'
ORDER  BY fecha_visita,
          O.dia,
          O.orden,
          C.fec_pln
```

Y este es el LINQ que tengo armado:

```
  string s = "12/20/2021";

                DateTime fec =
                    DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 



var query = from C in endtity.CLIENTEs.Distinct()
                            join O in endtity.alFAC_RUTA_ORDEN on new { C.COD_ZON, C.COD_CLT } equals new { O.COD_ZON, O.COD_CLT }
                            join V in endtity.VISITAs on C.COD_CLT equals V.CLIENTE into COV
                            from UN in COV.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where C.COD_ZON == "R03" && O.DIA == "L" && UN.INICIO >= fec
                            orderby UN.INICIO, O.DIA, O.ORDEN, C.FEC_PLN
                            select new
                            {
                                C.COD_CLT,
                                C.NOM_CLT,
                                C.DIR_CLT,
                                C.COD_ZON,
                                UN.INICIO,
                                O.DIA,
                                O.ORDEN,
                                C.FEC_PLN
                            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya logré resolverlo. Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
 DateTime fec =
                    DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                                    
                var query = from C in (endtity.CLIENTEs.Where(x=>x.COD_ZON==zona)).Distinct()
                            join O in (endtity.alFAC_RUTA_ORDEN.Where(x=>x.DIA==dia))
                            on new {C.COD_ZON,C.COD_CLT } equals new {O.COD_ZON,O.COD_CLT }
                            join V in (endtity.VISITAs.Where(x=>x.INICIO>=fec&&x.INICIO==null))
                            on C.COD_CLT equals V.CLIENTE
                            into COV from unidos in COV.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            orderby O.DIA, O.ORDEN, C.FEC_PLN
                            select new
                            {
                                C.COD_CLT, C.NOM_CLT, C.DIR_CLT, C.COD_ZON, COV, O.DIA, O.ORDEN, C.FEC_PLN
                            };



                var lista = query.ToList();
```